# How to execute particular method of another running java application

Tags: java

I have a third party GUI java application. I need to force this application to do some actions by calling it's methods from my app (for example: force aplication to logoff or login user, get current user info and etc). 
Which way I should use to do that if I know all the names of nesseary classes and methods?

Comment: That won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by running different commands according to your requirement  through your java program but then your program is not work properly on another operating system because there are different commands for different operating system.

**for eg:-To shutdown your window Computer in java**

```
String shutdownCmd = "shutdown -l"
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCmd);
```

or

```
String shutdownCmd = "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 0"
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shutdownCmd);
```